# How external user can access APS(Alfresco process service) without creating their account in APS?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share, aps

We have developed some workflows in Alfresco process service.
there are third party users which are not present in the APS.
Our requirement is we have to give them workflow access without creating those users in the APS.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality?
If yes then How can we achieve this? Please suggest the possible ways.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Give Alfresco Support a ring, they should be able to talk you through what's possible and what's advisable. You pay for them as part of your enterprise subscription for APS, so make use of it!

Comment: @Gagravarr, Thanks, But I have already spoken to Alfresco support, and they said that it's not possible as we have license fro 1000 users only. Now I just wanted to know from other experts whether we can achieve it by using other things like Open-cmis or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat : I am not a lawyer and would not want you to or advise you to joepardise your license agreement.

However I have seen this accomplished a couple of different ways.

1. Use a custom LDAP/Directory sync.
   ALfresco either retains users in a database table if using the internal authentication provider or syncs users from your LDAP server into the table once a day. The sync service copies the user ids and maintains capability references. User groups are pulled from LDAP as well. To my knowledge Alfresco does not monitor the number of users in the database, but this may have changed. However you could easily implement a different sync mechanism and also clear the table regularly so you dont go over your limit. This would also mean you would need a custom authentication provider (standard spring security plugin).
2. Use a proxy user for the "anonymous" users.
   For the UI that is being exposed to your "anonymous" users, create a system account that will be injected into the ReST requests by the front end UI. This system account should be very limited in capability for security and the page should have some sort of authentication to restrict specific content access.

I have seen both approaches used and they suit different scenarions.
Hopefully one of these will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your answer is really usefull